# mysql - can i copy a column and insert in another column without deleting other entries?

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql db, i would like to copy entries from a column to another column, but other column have already entries. it is possible? how can i do? for exp: i want to copy peoples column and add to c_tags without deleting old inserts

db:

```
cities        peoples                           c_tags
California    Clint Eastwood                    Sun
Roma          Sezar                             Collesium
Stuttgart     Die Fantastischen Vier            Mercedes,Porsche
```

Result:
db:

```
cities        peoples                       c_tags
California    Clint Eastwood                Sun,Clint Eastwood
Roma          Sezar                         Collesium,Sezar
Stuttgart     Die Fantastischen Vier        Mercedes,Porsche,Die Fantastischen Vier
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` to combine the two columns and update the `c_tags` column.

```
update your_table
set c_tags = concat(c_tags, ',', peoples);
```

If you don't want to update your table and just want to select as per your given result, you can do:

```
select cities, peoples, concat(c_tags, ',', peoples)
from your_table;
```